# Grouping JSON object by an attribute and splitting result in arrays PHP | Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to build the following query:

```
Model::where('id',$id)->groupBy('type')->get();
```

I get the following error.

> SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'db.table.id' which is
> not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group

Below is the result without group by. I'm trying to group by type and get an array for each type with objects in the array.

```
{
  'result':[
       {
         id:'1',
         name:first,
         type:animal 
       },       
       {
         id:'2',
         name:second,
         type:animal 
       },       
       {
         id:'3',
         name:third,
         type:human 
       }
   ]
}
```

What I'm trying to achieve:

```
{
 [
   {type:'animal',
    data:[..first,second]
   },
   {
   type:'human',
    data:[...third],
   }
 ]
}
```

Is there a way to achieve this with only `groupBy`? It doesn't have to be exact, but any way I can easily split items by type and with it as a key maybe?

Answer (score 1):

You can have the Collection do the `groupBy`:

```
$items = Model:....->get();

$grouped = $items->groupBy('type');
```

Then you would have an element for each 'type' and inside that would be a Collection of each object matching that type.